# My background image is not scaling correctly. I've changed the height to 100%, etc

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, background-image

My background image doesn't want to scale with the rest of the page. And when I've gotten it to do so, it created a huge white-space gap underneath it when I'm scaling down the page.

```
.vintage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(vintagemcdonalds.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: share some code or give a url, so that i can try to find asnwer

Comment: Ok. I'm fairly new to coding and to this site. When I try to paste the code it keeps saying I'm doing something wrong.. I'll figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

use `background-size:cover` for the `background-image` to cover the whole div.

see here more about this property : [CSS3 background-size Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

```css
.vintage { width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="vintage">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the property value **cover** to your css file.

Like this:

```
div {
background-image:url('vintagemcdonalds.jpg');
background-size:cover;
}
```

This **enables you to scale the background image to be as large as possible** so that the background area is completely covered by the background image.

If some parts of the background image are not visible within the background positioning area, try giving some extra information to your css such as:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

(Note that **CSS3 gives us viewport-relative units**. 100vw means 100% of the viewport width. 100vh; 100% of the height.)

If you don't want the background image to repeat simply add:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

For more info, check " https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ " it will give you a good idea of different approaches to be considered when trying to work with a full screen background.

Hope this helps and good luck! **:)**